# reload recyclerview after changing database data

Tags: android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I don't know what I have to do to reload my RecyclerView with ListItems.
What do I want to do? 
I created a simple fragment section project in Android Studio. After this I added one fragment which contains two buttons and another one which displays the data. 
The data comes from a sqlite database. So I created DBHelper class which does the connection to the database, a class TimeDataContent which loads the data from the database and stores it in an ArrayList.
The buttons in the Dialog Fragment add data to the Database.
For the RecyclerView fragment I have the Fragment class and RecyclerViewAdapter class (this comes from android studio).
At the moment I can add new elements to the database and load data into the RecyclerView.
But the next step, to update the RecyclerView after pressing the buttons doesn't work.
I tried some solutions from here, the last one exits with a NullpointerException.

Here is my code:

The fragment with the two buttons:
for now i call in setEnterTime() the updateList() method.

```
        public class EnterExitFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
        // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
        // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
        private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
        private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

        // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
        private String mParam1;
        private String mParam2;

        private DBHelper dbHelper;

        private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

        public EnterExitFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }

        /**
         * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
         * this fragment using the provided parameters.
         *
         * @param param1 Parameter 1.
         * @param param2 Parameter 2.
         * @return A new instance of fragment EnterExitFragment.
         */
        // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
        public static EnterExitFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
            EnterExitFragment fragment = new EnterExitFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
            args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            if (getArguments() != null) {
                mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
                mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
            }

            dbHelper =  new DBHelper(getActivity());
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_enter_exit, container, false);
            Button enter = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_enter);
            enter.setOnClickListener(this);
            Button exit = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_exit);
            exit.setOnClickListener(this);

            return view;
        }

        // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
        public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
            if (mListener != null) {
                mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Context context) {
            super.onAttach(context);
            if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
                mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
            } else {
                throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                        + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDetach() {
            super.onDetach();
            mListener = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()){
                case R.id.button_enter:
                    setEnterTime();
                    break;
                case R.id.button_exit:
                    setExitTime();
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void setEnterTime() {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            String valnow = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
            String text = getString(R.string.button_enter_toast) + " " +valnow;

            DBHelper db =  new DBHelper(getActivity());
            SQLiteDatabase dbsql = db.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            long id = 0;
            values.put(DBHelper.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID, id);
            values.put(DBHelper.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ENTER_TIME, valnow);
            values.put(DBHelper.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_EXIT_TIME,"");
            long newRowId;
            newRowId = dbsql.insert(
                    DBHelper.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                    null,
                    values);

            Toast.makeText(getContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            updateTimeList();

        }

        private void setExitTime() {
            // get actual time
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            String exitTimeNow = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
            //String text = getString(R.string.button_exit_toast) + " " +valnow;


            SQLiteDatabase dbsql = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            String[] projection = {
                    DBHelper.FeedEntry._ID,
                    DBHelper.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ENTER_TIME,
                    DBHelper.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_EXIT_TIME
                    //DBHelper.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_UPDATED
            };

            String sortOrder =
                    DBHelper.FeedEntry._ID + " DESC";

            Cursor c = dbsql.query(
                    DBHelper.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME,  // The table to query
                    projection,                               // The columns to return
                    null,//selection,                                // The columns for the WHERE clause
                    null,//selectionArgs,                            // The values for the WHERE clause
                    null,                                     // don't group the rows
                    null,                                     // don't filter by row groups
                    sortOrder                                 // The sort order
            );
            c.moveToFirst();
            long itemId = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBHelper.FeedEntry._ID));
            String exitTimeDB = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBHelper.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_EXIT_TIME));

            if(exitTimeDB.equals("")){
                // update time
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(DBHelper.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_EXIT_TIME, exitTimeNow);

                dbsql = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
                // Which row to update, based on the ID
                String selection = DBHelper.FeedEntry._ID + " LIKE ?";
                String[] selectionArgs = { String.valueOf(itemId) };

                int count = dbsql.update(
                        DBHelper.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                        values,
                        selection,
                        selectionArgs);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), getString(R.string.button_exit_toast) +" "+ exitTimeNow, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else{
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), getString(R.string.button_exit_error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        private void updateTimeList()
        {

            TimeStampFragment t2 = (TimeStampFragment)getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.list); // id of RecyclerView
            t2.updateTimeList();
        }

        /**
         * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
         * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
         * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
         * activity.
         * <p/>
         * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
         * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
         * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
         */
        public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
            // TODO: Update argument type and name
            void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
        }
     }

The Fragment with the RecyclerView:
in the onCreateView() I load the data from the database (later this is asynchronous) and add it to the adapter.

    public class TimeStampFragment extends Fragment {

        // TODO: Customize parameter argument names
        private static final String ARG_COLUMN_COUNT = "column-count";
        // TODO: Customize parameters
        private int mColumnCount = 1;
        private OnListFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
        private MyTimeStampRecyclerViewAdapter myTimeStampRecyclerViewAdapter;

        private TimeDataContent timeDataContent;

        /**
         * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
         * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
         */
        public TimeStampFragment() {
        }

        // TODO: Customize parameter initialization
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public static TimeStampFragment newInstance(int columnCount) {
            TimeStampFragment fragment = new TimeStampFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT, columnCount);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            if (getArguments() != null) {
                mColumnCount = getArguments().getInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT);
            }
            timeDataContent=new TimeDataContent(getContext());
            timeDataContent.loadData();
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_timestamp_list, container, false);

            // Set the adapter
            if (view instanceof RecyclerView) {
                Context context = view.getContext();
                RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view;
                if (mColumnCount <= 1) {
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
                } else {
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, mColumnCount));
                }
                myTimeStampRecyclerViewAdapter = new MyTimeStampRecyclerViewAdapter(timeDataContent.getTimeItemsList(), mListener);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(myTimeStampRecyclerViewAdapter);

            }
            return view;
        }

        public void updateTimeList() {
           // Toast.makeText(getContext(), getString(R.string.button_exit_error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Context context) {
            super.onAttach(context);
            if (context instanceof OnListFragmentInteractionListener) {
                mListener = (OnListFragmentInteractionListener) context;
            } else {
                throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                        + " must implement OnListFragmentInteractionListener");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDetach() {
            super.onDetach();
            mListener = null;
        }

        /**
         * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
         * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
         * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
         * activity.
         * <p/>
         * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
         * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
         * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
         */
        public interface OnListFragmentInteractionListener {
            // TODO: Update argument type and name
            void onListFragmentInteraction(TimeDataContent.TimeDataItem item);
        }

}
```

And my adapter:

```
    public class MyTimeStampRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyTimeStampRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private final List<TimeDataContent.TimeDataItem> mValues;
    private final OnListFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public MyTimeStampRecyclerViewAdapter(List<TimeDataContent.TimeDataItem> items, OnListFragmentInteractionListener listener) {
        mValues = items;
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.fragment_timestamp, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mItem = mValues.get(position);
        String id = String.valueOf(mValues.get(position).id);
        holder.mIdView.setText(id);
        holder.mContentView.setText(mValues.get(position).enterTime);

        holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (null != mListener) {
                    // Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the
                    // fragment is attached to one) that an item has been selected.
                    mListener.onListFragmentInteraction(holder.mItem);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mValues.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public final View mView;
        public final TextView mIdView;
        public final TextView mContentView;
        public TimeDataContent.TimeDataItem mItem;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mView = view;
            mIdView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id);
            mContentView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.content);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return super.toString() + " '" + mContentView.getText() + "'";
        }
    }
}
```

Even without code in the updateTimeList() in the fragment I get a NullPointerException.
I don't know whats wrong, if it's a design error or if there is something missing etc. ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: create new adapter after the data from database is received. Then set this adapter to the recyclerview

Comment: Thank you for your anwser.
I think I know now where my problem is. When i call the findFragmentByID in my updateTimeList() from my EnterExitFragment I get a null pointer exception because the TimeStamp Fragment is not active any more?